# How to create couchdb indexes in hyperledger-fabric with maven build

Tags: indexing, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to create couchdb indexes in hyperledger-fabric. I'm using maven as build tool. I added my index json files under `META-INF/statedb/couchdb/indexes` dir structure. I tried

- By adding this MATA-INF dir into the directory where the chaincode resides
- By adding this MATA-INF dir into the resources folder (`src\main\resources`)

But indexes were not created in both cases. I used following command to verify that indexes are created.

`docker logs <peer container name>  2>&1 | grep "CouchDB index"`

How do I create indexes?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your first attempt is the correct one. To make sure the chaincode was properly packed you can check out the `chaincode.tar.gz file`. If you open the file there should be one directory with the name of your chaincode and one file called metadata.json

If it's not the case than you need to include the META-INF directory in the `build/install/NAME_OF_YOUR_CHAINCODE` directory. I use gradle so I can't provide the proper commands in Maven to copy the META-INF.

Edit: I just tested the command you provide `docker logs <peer container name>  2>&1 | grep "CouchDB index"`. It didn't work for me as well. I had to use the docker container id: `docker logs <peer container id>  2>&1 | grep "CouchDB index"`